# Isolated RS485 without specialized IC

Tags: rs485, isolated

I'm looking for replacement for ADM2587E.

This is ADM2587E:

[image]

Can I just use cheap, not isolated RS485 transceiver like MAX485 connected to microcontroller TX, RX, DE/_RE via optocouplers and power it from isolated supply?

I realize, that it will take more space on PCB, but are there some other side-effects? Circuit is used for low speed communication (max baud rate is 38400).

Comment: Sure you could, if you properly design it.

Comment: Even without optos its possible. Analog Devices has some ICs in the same series (ADuM?) that are digital Isolators WITH isolated power. So 2 ICs only, ADuM + RS485. Same goes for other manufacturers, TI, etc.

Comment: It is possible so it depends how you design it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, as long as the digital isolators (e.g. optos) are fast enough for the baudrate you'll use.